# The column width of integer types is ignored in your MySQL version unless defining a TINYINT(1) column Documentation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an INT with primary key and auto AUTO_INCREMENT column in MYSQL and I'm getting this error  `The column width of integer types is ignored in your MySQL version unless defining a TINYINT(1) column Documentation`
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 8 ignoring integer lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60892749/mysql-8-ignoring-integer-lengths)

Comment: *What should I do to make it work?* What "it"? Precisely - how do you think it should work? What effect do you want to see?

Comment: *I'm getting this error* ?? You must receive a warning (code 1681). Shown error message is not MySQL text but the warning interpretation made by your programming language/library/tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the "length" part of the integer type. It is deprecated in the current version of MySQL.

WRONG:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
 id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ...
```

RIGHT:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ...
```

The "length" of an integer always meant almost nothing, even for TINYINT.

See my answer to [Types in MySQL: BigInt(20) vs Int(20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854)